# If W is a T-invariant subspace of V and W' is a subspace of W, is W' also T-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra

If W is a T-invariant subspace of V, then T(W) is contained in W, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the whole space $V$ is $T$-invariant for all linear transformations. If the theorem were true, wouldn't all subspaces be $T$-invariant, for all linear transformations $T$?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Consider $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ given by $T(x,y,z)=(y,x,z).$ If $W$ is the set of points $(x,y,0),$ then $W$ is $T$-invariant, but can readily be shown to have a proper subspace that is not.

As a side note, if it *were* true, then the only kind of linear transformation from *any* vector space to itself would be scalar multiples of the identity function. (Can you see why?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a rotation of $\Bbb R^2$ through an angle $\alpha\ne n\pi$.  Then the whole of $\Bbb R^2$ is obviously invariant, but a line through the origin is rotated to a different line and is therefore not invariant.